# How to include UserAuth context in React.js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication

I'm trying to implement a password protected area (UserArea) in my React app and I don't quite get how to correctly wrap the different components in my App.js file. For the authentication I use Firebase and I got the set up of the UserAuth context from a YouTube video.
This is my current status of App.js:

```js
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import About from './components/About/About';
import Blog from './components/Blog/Blog';
import Error from './components/Error/Error';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import Mitmachen from './components/Mitmachen/Mitmachen';
import LoginForm from './components/Signin/Signin';
import Projects from './components/Projekte/Projects';
import ProtectedRoute from './components/ProtectedRoute/ProtectedRoute';
import SharedLayout from './components/SharedLayout/SharedLayout';
import Testimonials from './components/Testimonials/Testimonials';
import UserArea from './components/UserArea/UserArea';
import Impressum from './components/Impressum/Impressum';

import { UserAuth } from './context/AuthContext';

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<SharedLayout />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="blog" element={<Blog />} />
            <Route path="mitmachen" element={<Mitmachen />} />
            <Route path="testimonials" element={<Testimonials />} />
            <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="projekte" element={<Projects />} />
            <Route path="impressum" element={<Impressum />} />
            <Route path="signin" element={<LoginForm />} />
            <Route path="userarea" element={
              <ProtectedRoute>
                <UserArea />
              </ProtectedRoute>
            } />
            <Route path="*" element={<Error />}/>
          </Route>
        </Routes> 
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The UserAuth context looks like this:

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../firebase';

const UserContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  const createUser = (email, password) => {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  };

   const signIn = (email, password) =>  {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
   };

  const logout = () => {
      return signOut(auth)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      console.log(currentUser);
      setUser(currentUser);
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ createUser, user, logout, signIn }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const UserAuth = () => {
  return useContext(UserContext);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I already tried to wrap the UserAuth context around all the components like this:

```js
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import About from './components/About/About';
import Blog from './components/Blog/Blog';
import Error from './components/Error/Error';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import Mitmachen from './components/Mitmachen/Mitmachen';
import LoginForm from './components/Signin/Signin';
import Projects from './components/Projekte/Projects';
import ProtectedRoute from './components/ProtectedRoute/ProtectedRoute';
import SharedLayout from './components/SharedLayout/SharedLayout';
import Testimonials from './components/Testimonials/Testimonials';
import UserArea from './components/UserArea/UserArea';
import Impressum from './components/Impressum/Impressum';

import { UserAuth } from './context/AuthContext';

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <UserAuth>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<SharedLayout />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="blog" element={<Blog />} />
            <Route path="mitmachen" element={<Mitmachen />} />
            <Route path="testimonials" element={<Testimonials />} />
            <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="projekte" element={<Projects />} />
            <Route path="impressum" element={<Impressum />} />
            <Route path="signin" element={<LoginForm />} />
            <Route path="userarea" element={
              <ProtectedRoute>
                <UserArea />
              </ProtectedRoute>
            } />
            <Route path="*" element={<Error />}/>
          </Route>
        </Routes> 
      </BrowserRouter>
     </UserAuth>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

But in this way it only shows a blank page.
When I only nest the "signing" and "userarea" routes in the UserAuth context I get the error that UserAuth is not a route.
Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance :)
Note: Yes, I'm quite new to React